# Why setState does not update my UI even it changes?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, mobile

I cannot understand why setState does not work. Because it is inside of Stateful Widget. There wouldn't be a problem. Here is my code part you can examine it.

```
class _MaintenanceScreenState extends State<MaintenanceScreen> {
  final col = MostColors();
  final colFr = FrenchColors();
  final colCh = ChineseColors();
  final api = MaintenanceApi();
  var updateFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final List<TotalMaintenance>? maintenances = MaintenanceApi.totalMtncList;
  List<TotalMaintenance>? _foundUsers = [];
  late String notes;
  DateFormat df= DateFormat('yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss');
  List<int>? statuses = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  int? selectedStatus;
  final List<int>? units = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  int? selectedUnit;
Widget getTakeEvent(int index) {
    return IconSlideAction(
      caption: "İşleme Al",
      color: colFr.frIcelandPoppy,
      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
      icon: Icons.update,
      onTap: () async {
          final resp = await api.takeEvent(
              ((selectedUnit==null || selectedUnit==3) && (selectedStatus==null || selectedStatus==3)
                  ? _foundUsers : (selectedUnit!=null && selectedUnit!=3) && (selectedStatus==null || selectedStatus==3)
                  ? _foundUsers?.where((element) => element.unitId==selectedUnit) :
              (selectedUnit==null || selectedUnit==3) && (selectedStatus!=null && selectedStatus!=3)
                  ? _foundUsers?.where((element) => element.status==selectedStatus) :
              _foundUsers?.where((element) => element.unitId==selectedUnit && element.status==selectedStatus))?.toList()[index].id, LoginApi.userId,
              LoginApi.userUnits[2].isExist == true ? 4 : 5, index);
          resp.statusCode == 200 ? Fluttertoast
              .showToast(
              msg: "İşleme Alındı",
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
              gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
              backgroundColor: colFr.frAuroraGreen,
              textColor: CupertinoColors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0) :
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "İşleme Alınamadı",
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
              gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
              backgroundColor: colFr.frTomatoRed,
              textColor: CupertinoColors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0);

          _refresh();
      },
    );
  }
...
@override
  initState() {
    _foundUsers = maintenances;
    super.initState();
  }
...
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
return Scaffold(
      //when the keyboard opens, resizeToAvoidBottomInset prevents unnecessarily blank space. check the scaffold number. if facing more blank space that you expect, check the nested scaffold situation.
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: col.mostGreyAccent,
      body: FutureBuilder<List<TotalMaintenance>>(
          future: api.getTotalMaintenances(LoginApi.userId, widget.locId),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              var filteredChoice = (selectedUnit==null || selectedUnit==3) && (selectedStatus==null || selectedStatus==3)
                  ? _foundUsers : (selectedUnit!=null && selectedUnit!=3) && (selectedStatus==null || selectedStatus==3)
                  ? _foundUsers?.where((element) => element.unitId==selectedUnit) :
              (selectedUnit==null || selectedUnit==3) && (selectedStatus!=null && selectedStatus!=3)
                  ? _foundUsers?.where((element) => element.status==selectedStatus) :
              _foundUsers?.where((element) => element.unitId==selectedUnit && element.status==selectedStatus);
              return RefreshWidget(
                onRefresh: _refresh,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: width,
                      height: getDeviceType()=='phone' ? height*.13 : height*.14,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, top:height*.03, bottom: height*.01, right: 16),
                        color: col.mostPurple,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                CupertinoButton(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,10,0,0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(CupertinoIcons.person_3_fill, color: CupertinoColors.white, size: width*.075,),
                                        Text('Birimler', style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.white),)
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () => {
                                      showUnitPicker()
                                    }
                                ),
                                CupertinoButton(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,10,0,0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(Icons.filter_list_alt, color: CupertinoColors.white, size: width*.075,),
                                        Text('Durumlar', style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.white),)
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () => {
                                      showStatusPicker()
                                    }
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Toplam Sorun: ${filteredChoice!.length} Adet\nİşleme Alınan Sorun: ${filteredChoice.where((element) => element.status==1).length} Adet\nÇözümlenen Sorun: ${filteredChoice.where((element) => element.status==2).length} Adet',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.white, fontSize: getDeviceType()=='phone' ? width*.04 : width*.03),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (value) => filteringBySearching(value),
                        cursorColor: col.mostDarkPurpleAccent,
                        style: TextStyle(color: col.mostDarkPurpleAccent),
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff3a2a6d)),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff3a2a6d)),
                            ),
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff3a2a6d)),
                            labelText: 'Operatör Ara', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Color(0xff3a2a6d),)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: filteredChoice.isNotEmpty
                            ? ListView.builder(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            itemCount: filteredChoice.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                              key: ValueKey(filteredChoice.toList()[index].id),
                              elevation: 4,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:2),
                              color: col.mostLightPurpleAccent,
                              child: Slidable(
                                actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                                actions: [
                                  IconSlideAction(
                                      caption: "Detaylar",
                                      color: colFr.frFlatFresh,
                                      foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                                      icon: Icons.description,
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        Navigator.of(context)
                                            .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                MaintenanceLogScreen(userId:filteredChoice.toList()[index].userId, locId: widget.locId, maintenanceId: filteredChoice.toList()[index].id)));
                                      }
                                  )
                                ],
                                secondaryActions: getSlidableButtons(filteredChoice.toList()[index].status!, index),
                                child:  ListTile(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  leading: Container(
                                    width: width * .15,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: col.mostDarkPurpleAccent,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                    ),
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        '${filteredChoice.toList()[index].equipmentCode!}',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  title: Container(
                                      width: width * .7,
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Text( getDeviceType()=='phone' ?
                                          "Açıklama: ${filteredChoice.toList()[index].description!}\nOluşturma:\n${df.format(DateTime.parse(filteredChoice.toList()[index].createdDate!.toString()))}\nGüncellenme:\n${df.format(DateTime.parse(filteredChoice.toList()[index].progressDate!.toString()))}":
                                          "Açıklama: ${filteredChoice.toList()[index].description!}\nOluşturma: ${df.format(DateTime.parse(filteredChoice.toList()[index].createdDate!.toString()))}\nGüncellenme: ${df.format(DateTime.parse(filteredChoice.toList()[index].progressDate!.toString()))}",
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: width*.0275),
                                          ),
                                          Text("${filteredChoice.toList()[index].userName?.toLowerCase()}",
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: width*.0275),)
                                        ],
                                      )
                                  ),
                                  trailing: Container(
                                    width: width * .15,
                                    child: Center(
                                        child: iconPicker(filteredChoice.toList(), index, height)
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                        )
                            : Center(
                            child: const Text(
                              'Aradığınız kriterlere uygun bakım bulunamadı.',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff3a2a6d)),
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
            else if(snapshot.data?.length==0) {
              return Center(
                child: Text("Bakım Bulunamadı.", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Color(0xff3a2a6d))),
              );
            }
            else {
              _refresh();
              return LoadingScreen();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
Future _refresh() async {
    return api.getTotalMaintenances(LoginApi.userId, widget.locId).then((value) {
      setState(() {
      });
    });
  }
}
```

After i added filtering it is not working properly and not updating the UI. Where is the problem i cannot understand. Is there anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign `_foundUsers= snapshot.data;` before var filteredChoice=...